# Tensorflow DecodeJPEG: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\00'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm cycling through an image folder and this keeps happening.

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with '\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000'
> [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]

There are files in this folder that aren't images, but they should be filtered by my previous step. Anyone has an idea of what's going on?

```
test_files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(myFolder + '/*.jpg') 

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE


def process_unlabeled_img(file_path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    img = tf.image.resize(images=img, size=(224, 224))
    return file_path, img
```

Comment: First 3 bytes of any JPEG file are `FFD8FF`, if it starts with zeroes, something's wrong with the file.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65833770/invalidargumenterror-assertion-failed-unable-to-decode-bytes-as-jpeg-png-gi/65834243#65834243

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what is going on without having the file at hand, but  what is probably happening here is that you have files in your dataset that have either a `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png` or `.gif` extension but that are not actually JPEG, PNG of GIF images. Thus, TensorFlow isn't able to properly load them.

One way to overcome this problem would be to check your files that are supposedly images and get rid of the ones that aren't actual JPEG, PNG or GIF images.

Checking if a file is a *valid* JPEG, PNG or GIF image is definitely more complicated than it seems, but checking for the file signature / magic number (that is, the first few bytes of your file) is a good start and should most of the time solve your problems.

So, practically, you could do so in many different ways, one of which being checking for each picture individually if it is *valid* or not, with some function of this sort:

```
def is_image(filename, verbose=False):

    data = open(filename,'rb').read(10)

    # check if file is JPG or JPEG
    if data[:3] == b'\xff\xd8\xff':
        if verbose == True:
             print(filename+" is: JPG/JPEG.")
        return True

    # check if file is PNG
    if data[:8] == b'\x89\x50\x4e\x47\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a':
        if verbose == True:
             print(filename+" is: PNG.")
        return True

    # check if file is GIF
    if data[:6] in [b'\x47\x49\x46\x38\x37\x61', b'\x47\x49\x46\x38\x39\x61']:
        if verbose == True:
             print(filename+" is: GIF.")
        return True

    return False
```

You would then be able to **get rid** of your *non valid* images by doing something like this (this would **delete** your *non valid* images):

```
import os

# go through all files in desired folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
     # check if file is actually an image file
     if is_image(filename, verbose=False) == False:
          # if the file is not valid, remove it
          os.remove(os. path. join(folder, filename))
```

Now, as I said, this would probably solve your problem but please note that the function `is_image` will **not** be able to tell for sure if a file can or cannot be read as a JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF image. It is only a quick and dirty solution that will get the vast majority of errors alike away, but not all.

Comment: That looks very promising. I'll check it out when I get the chance.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know what this is: `Invalid argument: Invalid JPEG data or crop window, data size 103077`?

Comment: Well I would say it's another type of data corruption. I'd suggest you try to identify from which file the error originates to better understand where's the problem coming from and most probably how the supposedly JPEG file is corrupted!

Comment: @bglbrt thank you this helped a lot with debugging a problem passing images through the keras image data loader