# InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pathlib

I have a folder structure where every subfolder represents a class, for every class there is exactly one example picture. I want to load the data in a Keras dataset as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory
I expect to get the tuple "(images, labels)" returned, but when I assign the functions output to a tuple, I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
import pathlib
data_path = "./patterns"
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_path)

batch_size = 32
img_height = 120
img_width = 30

train_ds, train_labels = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  labels='inferred',
  label_mode='categorical', #int
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
Found 2160 files belonging to 2160 classes.
Using 1728 files for training.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py in execution_mode(mode)
   2101       ctx.executor = executor_new
-> 2102       yield
   2103     finally:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in _next_internal(self)
    757             output_types=self._flat_output_types,
--> 758             output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
    759 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py in iterator_get_next(iterator, output_types, output_shapes, name)
   2609     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 2610       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   2611     except _core._FallbackException:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6842   # pylint: disable=protected-access
-> 6843   six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
   6844   # pylint: enable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]
     [[{{node decode_image/cond_jpeg/else/_1/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/else/_20/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/else/_39/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert/Assert}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-f878a6f234dd> in <module>
      7   seed=123,
      8   image_size=(img_height, img_width),
----> 9   batch_size=batch_size)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in __next__(self)
    734 
    735   def __next__(self):  # For Python 3 compatibility
--> 736     return self.next()
    737 
    738   def _next_internal(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in next(self)
    770   def next(self):
    771     try:
--> 772       return self._next_internal()
    773     except errors.OutOfRangeError:
    774       raise StopIteration

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py in _next_internal(self)
    762         return self._element_spec._from_compatible_tensor_list(ret)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    763       except AttributeError:
--> 764         return structure.from_compatible_tensor_list(self._element_spec, ret)
    765 
    766   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
    128                 value = type()
    129             try:
--> 130                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    131             except StopIteration as exc:
    132                 # Suppress StopIteration *unless* it's the same exception that

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py in execution_mode(mode)
   2103     finally:
   2104       ctx.executor = executor_old
-> 2105       executor_new.wait()
   2106 
   2107 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/executor.py in wait(self)
     65   def wait(self):
     66     """Waits for ops dispatched in this executor to finish."""
---> 67     pywrap_tfe.TFE_ExecutorWaitForAllPendingNodes(self._handle)
     68 
     69   def clear_error(self):

InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]
     [[{{node decode_image/cond_jpeg/else/_1/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/else/_20/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/else/_39/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert/Assert}}]]
```

Anyway it is interesting that I still get the output:

```
Found 2160 files belonging to 2160 classes.
Using 1728 files for training.
```

When I assign the function output just to a single variable (train_ds), I do not receive an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* one of your images is corrupted. Use this function and see if it crashes. It will print the filename before reading it, so you'll see which picture is corrupted.

Modify the `os.listdir()` part so it includes all your images in the different folders.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

def validate_image(file_name):
    tf.py_function(tf.print, inp=[file_name], Tout=[])
    image = tf.io.read_file(file_name)
    image = tf.io.decode_image(image, channels=3)
    return image

os.chdir(r'path\to\images')

accepted_extensions = ('jpg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif')

files = list(filter(lambda x: x.lower().endswith(accepted_extensions), os.listdir()))

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(files).map(validate_image)

for i in ds:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you, actually some of the image files were corrupted!