# How can I skip over whatever image is raising a PIL Unidentified Image Error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, python-imaging-library

When running my CNN model, I get the following error:
 `PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff948801680>`
I don't know how to find which image is causing this error or how to write code that can fix the image(s). If anyone could provide insight as to how I can either:

1. Skip over the problem image(s)
2. Find the filepath of the image(s)
3. Write code that will account for the image(s) that would raise this kind of error
   I would really appreciate it!
   My relevant code is below.

```
                            shear_range=.15,
                            zoom_range=.2,
                            height_shift_range=0.2,
                            width_shift_range=0.2,
                            rotation_range=20,
                            fill_mode='nearest')
train_generator=image_gen.flow_from_directory(directory=train_path,
                                             target_size=(100,100),
                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                             batch_size=32)
test_generator=image_gen.flow_from_directory(directory=test_path,
                                            target_size=(100,100),
                                            class_mode='categorical',
                                            batch_size=32)
Found 3104 images belonging to 23 classes.
Found 777 images belonging to 23 classes.
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

model=Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, input_shape=(100,100,3), activation='relu', kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, activation='relu', kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, activation='relu', kernel_size=(3,3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(23, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=5, validation_data=test_generator)
Epoch 1/5
17/97 [====>.........................] - ETA: 2:12 - loss: 3.1605 - accuracy: 0.0478
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-ba2841f6dbb4> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(train_generator, epochs=5, validation_data=test_generator)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    915       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    916       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 917       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    918     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    919       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3021       (graph_function,
   3022        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 3023     return graph_function._call_flat(
   3024         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3025 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1958         and executing_eagerly):
   1959       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1960       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1961           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1962     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    589       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    590         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 591           outputs = execute.execute(
    592               str(self.signature.name),
    593               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnknownError:  UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff948801680>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 249, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 645, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 961, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 837, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 963, in generator_fn
    yield x[i]

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 227, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    img = load_img(filepaths[j],

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 114, in load_img
    img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))

  File "/Users/liatkatz/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2967, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7ff948801680>


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1713]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: How about using a quick `glob` of your directory of images and doing PIL `Image.open()` on each till it fails?

Comment: maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65834243/10908375)