# tf.image.decode_jpeg often taking forever to load file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The following code is part of my code for a tf graph to read images. When I use this code to iterate through the data, the program gets stuck in `tf.io.read_file(path)` after a few hundred images forever and doesn't do anything. More specifically, the code even can't be paused and I had to restart the session every time.

```
@tf.function()
def read_image(path):
  image = tf.io.read_file(path)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
  return image

...

div8k_list=[os.path.join(div8k_save_path, x) for x in os.listdir(div8k_save_path)]
train_path = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(div8k_list)

train_images = train_path.map(read_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

I first suspected that there were a few corrupted images or wrong paths in the data that were causing this problem and tested the following code.

```
for path in train_path:
  print(path)
  
  image = tf.io.read_file(path)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
```

Surprisingly, there was no common characteristic of the image path the loop was stuck. And it was not a problem of the image because the loop was once stuck at `1056.png` but when I explicitly loaded `1056.png`, there was no problem.

What could be the cause of this problem?

edit: to summarize, the program is stuck at `read_image` forever, while I couldn't find a problem in the dataset.

My dataset is the DIV8K dataset and I am running in COLAB.

**EDIT** The function that is slowing my code is `decode_jpeg`, because the following definition of `read_image` worked multiple times.

```
@tf.function()
def read_image(path):
  image = tf.io.read_file(path)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
  return image
```

Comment: I am willing to share my COLAB environment but unfortunately, the data is in my Google Drive account and it is too big(~50GB).

Comment: Can you try `tf.io.decode_image(image, expand_animations = False)` instead of `tf.image.decode_jpeg`?

Comment: @M.Innat Thank you! I will try it out. Thanks to you, I figured that the problem was with tf.image.decode_jpeg

Comment: @M.Innat Thank you so much! You saved my life! I still don't understand why `tf.image.decode_jpeg` has an issue while `tf.io.decode_image` works just fine. Please post an answer so you can receive the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, try the following function to decode the image file as it can handle mixed extension file format (`jpg`, `png` etc), [ref](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/decode_image).

```
tf.io.decode_image(image, expand_animations = False)
```

---

However, `decode_jpeg` should also able to handle the `.png` file format now. Without the image file, it's hard to break down what's causing to prevent this. Most probably the file is somehow corrupted or not the valid extension for the `decode_jpeg`, though it's named that way, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544801/9215780) solution.